How do I add a 2nd light to an existing 3 way switch circuit
I want to add a 2nd light to an existing 3 way switch circuit which has the light in the middle of the run. I do not have access to the 1st switch which is connected to the power source. Connecting to the light in the middle is possible but with much construction to access it, so I hope I can connect to the 2nd switch. How can I do this ?

Show us (include pictures) the wiring in both switch boxes and at the light. [Edit] your post to add them using the Sun & Mountains icon.

If your wiring is exactly the same as the diagram (Warning: there are a lot of ways to wire up a 3-way switch, so it might not be the same.) then you can't do it. The left switch box has neutral but does not have switched hot. The right switch box has switched hot but does not have neutral. The only place that has what you need - switched hot and neutral - is the existing light box. Add a /2 cable to extend from the existing light (black/switched hot and white/neutral) to the new light.
